# How to calculate unique values in pandas dataframe while grouping by values of particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns **ip**, **mac**, **hostname**, and **os**. I want to convert that DataFrame DataFrame into a new DataFrame where the **ip** column is unique, and the other columns list all the unique values that appear with the given **ip**.

For example, a DataFrame as follows

> | ip | mac | hostname | os |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 8.8.8.8 | 00:00:00:ff | dns.google.com | linux |
> | 8.8.8.8 | 00:00:ff:ff | dns2.google.com | windows |
> | 8.8.8.8 | 00:00:ff:ff | dns2.google.com | windows |
> | 8.8.4.4 | 00:00:00:ff | dns.google.com | linux |
> | 8.8.4.4 | 00:00:ff:ff | dns2.google.com | windows |
> | 8.8.4.4 | 00:00:ff:ff | dns2.google.com | windows |

should be converted into the following

> | ip | mac | hostname | os |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 8.8.8.8 | 00:00:00:ff, 00:00:ff:ff | dns.google.com,dns2.google.com | linux,windows |
> | 8.8.4.4 | 00:00:00:ff, 00:00:ff:ff | dns.google.com,dns2.google.com | linux,windows |

I can accomplish the desired behavior by running

```py
df.groupby('ip').agg(set)
```

but the data set is very large, and groupby is very memory intensive, so a 500MB dataset is consuming 3-4GB of memory. Is there an alternative way of doing this that is not so memory intensive?

Code for creating the input data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ip': ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4', '8.8.4.4', '8.8.4.4'],
        'mac': ['00:00:00:ff', '00:00:ff:ff', '00:00:ff:ff', '00:00:00:ff', '00:00:ff:ff', '00:00:ff:ff'],
        'hostname': ['dns.google.com', 'dns2.google.com', 'dns2.google.com', 'dns.google.com', 'dns2.google.com', 'dns2.google.com',],
        'os': ['linux', 'windows', 'windows', 'linux', 'windows', 'windows'],
    }
)
```

Comment: Are duplicated values always duplicated in all fields? If yes, you should maybe first `drop_duplicates`

Comment: drop_duplicates ended up removing 4,790 rows from a 805,235 row dataframe, so definitely helps on the margin, but there aren't many pure duplicates in the data.

Comment: Then I'm afraid this is the best you can get with pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.groupby('ip').agg(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(set(x))))
```

Joining the unique elements directly will reduce memory, as a single string will be stored in each cell instead of a set of strings.

Comment: Wow, this reduced memory usage by 70%! How does that work?

Comment: @Peter Instead of storing a set in each cell, joining the items directly will lead to only a string being stored, which will take up less memory.

Comment: This ended up having weird behavior when the dataframe included non str-type columns, but that issue was resolved by running `df=df.astype(str)` prior to the aggregation.